# function that takes a list of intergers from a textfile and return the min, max,and avg

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this one

```
[['min: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6\n'], 
['max: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6\n'], 
['avg: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6']]
```

on a textfile.

I would like to calculate the min, max and avg but i am having trouble removing min, max and avg on the list.

```
infile = open('input.txt', 'r+')
lisnum = []
for line in infile:
    listnum.append(line.split(','))
for i in listnum:
    print i
infile.close()

def minimum(mi):
    min_value = min(mi)
    return min_value

def maximum(ma):
    max_value = max(ma)
    return max_value

def average(avg):
    sum = 0
    for x in av:
        sum+=x
    return(sum/len(av))

print listnum
a = [i.split(':')[0] for i in listnum]
print a
print minimum(listnum)
print maximum(listnum)
print average(listnum)
```

Comment: what trouble are you having exactly. post some code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: As danidee said, post some code of what you have tried so far, also the expected output. Furthermore the 6 in avg has no \n, is this on purpose?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think it is a bit too early to close this, it seems like he has tried something.

Comment: @Altoyr there's still no [mcve], *"having trouble"* is not a useful problem description. It should definitely be closed until the OP adds more information.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using `split(',')` on something that is not a CSV file (comma-separated values). You could treat the first value in the list separately, using `split(':')[1]` to get the part after the `:`, but instead I suggest to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to get all the numbers in the list:

```
>>> line = 'max: 1,2,3,5,6\n'
>>> re.findall('\d+', line)
['1', '2', '3', '5', '6']
>>> nums = [int(x) for x in re.findall('\d+', line)]
>>> min(nums)
1
```

Also, it seems like you are applying your functions to the entire list of lists, instead of just to the respective lines. To get, e.g., the `max` for the "max" line, use `print maximum(listnum[1])`

---

Seems like you are still having problems with this. As I said, you can not split the entire list by `,` because the entire list is not separated by `,`. You can either use a regular expression to get both the operation and the numbers, or you can *first* split by `:` and *then* by `,`. Just try this:

```
operations = {"sum": sum, "min": min, "max": max,
              "avg": lambda lst: float(sum(lst))/len(lst)}

with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        op, numbers = line.split(":")
        op = op.strip().lower()
        numbers = [float(n) for n in numbers.split(",")]
        if op in operations:
            print("%s of %r is %f" % (op, numbers, operations[op](numbers)))
        else:
            print("Don't know how to do %s" % op)
```

Output:

```
min of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0] is 1.000000
max of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0] is 6.000000
avg of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0] is 3.400000
Don't know how to do p90
sum of [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] is 21.000000
Don't know how to do p70
```

Comment: I have a file contaning the following :                                                                ['min: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6\n']
['max: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6\n']
['avg: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6\n']
['P90: 1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '10\n']
['Sum: 1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6\n']
['P70: 1', '2', '3', '\n'](each list on a different line)                                                                              and now I want to remove everything before 1 for each line in my text file so I can do my calculations for each line. Can I do this using re.findal or any other way?

Comment: @Sine Do the files contain _exactly_ this, including the `[` and `'`, or did you split the content of the file by `,` again, although it is obviously not a CSV file?

Comment: it a text file containing these each in different line: min: 1,2,3,5,6
max: 1,2,3,5,6
avg: 1,2,3,5,6
P90: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
Sum: 1,2,3,4,5,6
P70: 1,2,3, i then read it into a list like this ['min: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6\n']
['max: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6\n']
['avg: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6\n']
['P90: 1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '10\n']
['Sum: 1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6\n']
['P70: 1', '2', '3', '\n']
[70, 1, 2, 3] each list in a different line.

Comment: @Sine Well, the point of my answer was _not_ to read them into a list like that in the first place. Don't do `split(',')` on something that's not really comma-separated.

Comment: Ok then how do I extract only the numbers in each line so i can do my calculations?